# OpenAPI Generator typescript-angular generates failing services

Tags: angular, typescript, swagger, openapi

When using [this OpenApi generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/typescript-angular) version 2.4.26 ("@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli": "^2.4.26") I am getting failing angular services (Angular Verision 13.2.0). Eg. they pass to many arguments to the Angular HttpClient so that the code wont even compile.

I generate the code with the following command: `openapi-generator-cli generate -i https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openapitools/openapi-generator/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/test/resources/3_0/petstore.yaml -g typescript-angular -o libs/openapi.`

Am i missing some properties here that i have to pass in?
Or is there a angular openapi-genererator compatibility table or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

same here, also specifying with --additional-properties=ngVersion=13.2.4. error:Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to this issue (https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/10864) where the generator creates a delete method with an additional `null` value for the request body. Temporarily, the error is quickly resolved when you remove the second argument from the method.

Example:

```js
        return this.httpClient.delete<any>(`${this.configuration.basePath}/api/foo/bar/${encodeURIComponent(String(id))}`,
            null,   // <--- this is the argument you want to remove
            {
                context: localVarHttpContext,
                responseType: <any>responseType_,
                withCredentials: this.configuration.withCredentials,
                headers: localVarHeaders,
                observe: observe,
                reportProgress: reportProgress
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issues. Out of the blue I couldn't generate code for DELETE endpoints anymore. Solved it by setting the 'ngVersion' additional-property to '12.0.0' (although the project is on v14) in the command:

```
openapi-generator-cli generate -i http://localhost:XXXX/.../swagger.json -g typescript-angular -o src/generated/api --additional-properties=withInterfaces=true --additional-properties=ngVersion=12.0.0
```

setting it to any major version above "12.0.0" will break the code generation.